# Pop-up modal on each element of a list

Tags: php, html, mysql, modal-dialog

recently I,ve been trying to make a modal to pop-up on every element of a list. That list comes from a MySQL Database with this code:

```
<?php
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
$cadenaSQL = "SELECT idPedido, fecha, fechaActual, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, telefono, email, productos, mensaje, aprobado
    FROM pedido
    WHERE borrado = 0
    ORDER BY -fecha";
$limit = 10;
$page = validatepage($mysqli,$cadenaSQL,$limit,$page);
$startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

$res= $mysqli->query($cadenaSQL." LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}"); 
?>
```

Most of the code above comes from a php class with functions related to the database, so they are called from there.

It shows on a list with the following html-php code, relating almost every field of the database, posting it first on a column with the showed width and then making every line with the values from every entry:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th scope="col"  style="width:8%" class="num-pedido">NºPedido</th>
                                    <th scope="col"  style="width:10%" class="fecha">Fecha</th>
                                    <th scope="col"  style="width:15%" class="nombre-completo">Nombre</th>
                                    <th scope="col"  style="width:12%" class="telefono">Teléfono</th>
                                    <th scope="col"  style="width:15%" class="email">Email</th>
                                    <th scope="col"  style="width:20%" class="productos">Productos</th>
                                    <th scope="col"  style="width:10%" class="aprobado">Aceptado</th>
                                    <th scope="col"  style="width:10%" class="accion">Acción</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                                            $idPedido = $row['idPedido'];
                                            $id = "P".str_pad($idPedido, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                                            $fecha = $row['fecha'];
                                            $fechaActual = $row['fechaActual'];;
                                            $nombre = $row['nombre'];
                                            $apellido1 = $row['apellido1'];
                                            $apellido2 = $row['apellido2'];
                                            $telefono = $row['telefono'];
                                            $email = $row['email'];
                                            $productos = $row['productos'];
                                            $aprobado = $row['aprobado'].'';
                                            $mensaje = $row['mensaje'];
                                            $nombrecompleto = $nombre." ".$apellido1." ".$apellido2;

                                    ?>
                                    <tr class="tabla-fila" <?php if($aprobado==1){echo "style='background:#afd5a2'";}?>>                                          
                                        <td data-label="Nº Pedido">           
                                            <a>
                                                <div class="num-pedido" ><div id="myModalBtn"><?=$id?></div></div>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>                                          
                                        <td data-label="Fecha">
                                            <div class="fecha"><?=$fecha?></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Nombre">
                                            <div class="nombre-completo-pedido"><?=$nombrecompleto?></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Telefono">
                                            <div class="telefono"><?=$telefono?></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Email">
                                            <div class="email-pedido"><?=$email?></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Productos">
                                            <div class="productos"><?=$productos?></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Aceptado">
                                            <div class="aprobado"><?php if($aprobado==0){
                                                echo "NO";
                                            }else{
                                                echo "SI";
                                            }?></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Acción">
                                            <div class="accion">
                                                    <span class="ti-check" id='<?=$idPedido?>' data-id="<?= $idPedido ?>"></span>
                                                    <span class="ti-trash" id='<?=$idPedido?>' data-id='<?= $idPedido ?>'></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

The problem comes when I try to call the model with "myModalBtn" (I will post the code a few lines later), as it only shows the last entry of my database. Here is the code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class=>
                        <button class="close">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <?php sectionbradcam('Detalles del pedido');?> 
                    <section class="subcaja-central">
                        <div id = "central" class="container">
                            <div class="area-contenido">
                                <p><br>
                                Id Pedido: <?=$id?><br>
                                Fecha solicitada: <?=$fecha?><br>
                                Fecha de la solicitud: <?=$fechaActual?><br>
                                Nombre completo: <?=$nombrecompleto?><br>
                                Teléfono: <?=$telefono?><br>
                                Email: <?=$email?><br>
                                Productos: <?=$productos?><br>
                                Mensaje: <?=$mensaje?><br>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And also the json called to make the modal popup:

```
// Get the modal

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal

var btn = document.getElementById("myModalBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

How can I make it on every item of the list I mentioned above? And how would I point each lane of the list to it´s information on the database?

Thanks in advance to everyone who can help me.

Comment: Please show us _all_ relevant code and not just some snippets here and there. We need to see the context and how the information flows from the database all the way to the output, or we won't have a single clue what's going on.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry, I'm new to this, let me edit it with every piece of code from the database to the output